# Why am I not getting didEnterRegion or didExitRegion calls when using CLLocationManager's startMonitoringForRegion

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, geofencing, region-monitoring

I am trying to set up a client's app to trigger a database update when the iOS device arrives at/leaves the office.

(It's an app for my client's salespeople to use in the field, where some customer sites do not have any network connectivity, so the client wants the database updated as the salespeople leaves the office/return to the office.)

I am never getting `didEnterRegion` or `didExitRegion` calls.

I have a singleton `RegionsManager` that manages an instance of the location manager.
I am using `CLLocationManager` and the `startMonitoringForRegion` method.

On launch, I invoke the  the `RegionsManager` which creates a location manager and set itself up as the delegate of the location manager.

In my app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method I check for the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey`, in case I'm being relaunched for a region entered/exited, but that never happens.

I have a `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key/value pair in info.plist.

I call `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus` to make sure the app is authorized, and if not I call `requestAlwaysAuthorization`.

Once I verify that the app is authorized, I also check isMonitoringAvailableForClass(CLCircularRegion).

Assuming monitoring is available, I then check to see if the location manager's set of `monitoredRegions` already contains the region I am about to create (I just check the coordinate). If so, I skip adding the region.

If the location manager is not yet monitoring the region, I add it with a call to `startMonitoringForRegion`.

On the second launch of the app, I see the regions that I added on the last launch in the location manager's set of `monitoredRegions`, so I know they are being added.

The code to set all this up is quite involved, since it is set up to handle adding multiple regions, and also has logic to maintain an array of the regions being monitored and a block that should be invoked if the on a `didEnterRegion` or `didExitRegion` message.

Here is the method in question in it's (rather long) entirety:

```
func startMonitoring(#coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D,
  radius: CLLocationDistance = regionDistance,
  id: String = "",
  notificationBlock: regionNotificationBlock)
{
  var authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
  if !locationManagerReady
  {
    //Make sure we're authorized to use the location manager.
    if authorizationStatus == .NotDetermined && !waitingForAuthorization
    {
      //We haven't been authorized yet. Trigger a prompt to the user.
      theLocationMgr.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
      waitingForAuthorization = true
      authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    }

    //Wait for the user to grant/deny permission.
    if authorizationStatus == .NotDetermined
    {
      //After 1 second, re-call this method to try again.
      delay(1.0)
        {
          ()-> () in
          self.startMonitoring(
            coordinate: coordinate,
            radius: radius,
            id: id,
            notificationBlock: notificationBlock)
      }
      return
    }

    let rootVC: UIViewController? = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
    if authorizationStatus == CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted ||
      authorizationStatus == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied
    {
      Utils.showAlertOnVC(
        rootVC,
        title: "Location manager error",
        message: "Permission to access location denied")
      return
    }

    else if !CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailableForClass(CLCircularRegion)
    {
      Utils.showAlertOnVC(
        rootVC,
        title: "Location manager error",
        message: "geofencing is not available.")
      return
    }
  }
  if !locationManagerReady
  {
    locationManagerReady = true
    theLocationMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    theLocationMgr.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
  }

  //If we get here, we're done configuring the location manager

  //If this region is already in our array of regions, don't add it again.
  if let existingRegionIndex = regionIndexForCoordinate(coordinate)
  {
    return
  }
  let regionToMonitor =  CLCircularRegion(
    center: coordinate,
    radius: radius,
    identifier: id)


  //See if the system is still monitoring this region from a previous launch.
  var found = false
  var foundRegion: CLCircularRegion? = nil
  if let monitoredRegions = theLocationMgr.monitoredRegions as NSSet?
  {
    let regionsArray = monitoredRegions.allObjects as NSArray
    let regionIndex = regionsArray.indexOfObjectPassingTest()
      { (object, index, flag) -> Bool in
        if let region = object as? CLCircularRegion
        {
          return region.center.latitude == coordinate.latitude &&
            region.center.longitude == coordinate.longitude
        }
        else
        {
          return false
        }
    }
    found = regionIndex != NSNotFound
    if found
    {
      foundRegion = regionsArray[regionIndex] as? CLCircularRegion
    }
  }
  if found
  {
    logToFile("already monitoring (\(coordinate.latitude),\(coordinate.longitude)). ID = '\(foundRegion!.identifier!)'")
  }
  else
  {
    logToFile("Adding geofence for (\(coordinate.latitude),\(coordinate.longitude)). ID = '\(id)'")
    theLocationMgr.startMonitoringForRegion(regionToMonitor)
  }
  let aRegionEntry = RegionEntry(region: regionToMonitor, regionNoticeBlock: notificationBlock)
  regionsBeingMonitored.append(aRegionEntry)
}
```

My RegionsManager class has an array `regionsBeingMonitored` of `RegionEntry` objects:

```
lazy var regionsBeingMonitored = [RegionEntry]()
```

Here is the RegionEntry object:

```
class RegionEntry: NSObject
{
  var theRegion: CLCircularRegion?
  var theRegionNoticeBlock: regionNotificationBlock?
  init(region: CLCircularRegion?, regionNoticeBlock: regionNotificationBlock?)
  {
    theRegion = region
    theRegionNoticeBlock = regionNoticeBlock
  }
}
```

It also has state flags to keep track of the setup of the location manager:

```
var waitingForAuthorization: Bool = false
var locationManagerReady: Bool = false
```

I have gone over the documentation on setting up region monitoring quite carefully and am pretty confident I am doing all the setup I am supposed to be doing.

My didEnterRegion and didExitRegion methods write a message to a log file as soon as they are called, so even if there is a problem with my logic for matching a region with an entry in my `regionsBeingMonitored` array I should still see the log entry:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
  didEnterRegion region: CLRegion!)
{
  logToFile("In \(__FUNCTION__). region = \(region)")
  if let region = region as? CLCircularRegion
  {
    if let regionIndex = regionIndexForCoordinate(region.center)
    {
      let aRegionEntry = regionsBeingMonitored[regionIndex]
      aRegionEntry.theRegionNoticeBlock?(region: region, didEnter: true)
    }
  }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
  didExitRegion region: CLRegion!)
{
  logToFile("In \(__FUNCTION__). region = \(region)")
  if let region = region as? CLCircularRegion
  {
    if let regionIndex = regionIndexForCoordinate(region.center)
    {
      let aRegionEntry = regionsBeingMonitored[regionIndex]
      aRegionEntry.theRegionNoticeBlock?(region: region, didEnter: false)
    }
  }
}
```

Do you see anything that I might be doing wrong? The method signature for my `didEnterRegion` or `didExitRegion` looks correct, so I don't think that's it.

Comment: That's some pretty nasty/confusing/unnecessary/expensive recursion in that massive `startMonitoring` method.  Why aren't you using a delegate waiting for the `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` call?

Comment: Which... may be related to your problem.  `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` is called on the delegate.  So are the `didEnter` and `didExit` methods.  Are you setting the delegate somewhere and I overlooked it?  You have to set the delegate.

Comment: You didn't miss the code assigning my delegate. It's in the init method, but it is being set.

Comment: I didn't use the `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus` method because I didn't know about it. That is cleaner, for sure. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @nhgrif, thanks for pointing me in the direction of the `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus` method. I restructured my code check for/ask for authorization first, with the code to set the regions for monitoring passed in as a block that gets executed when the `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus` is called. Much cleaner.